# Windows Start Menu Not Working

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

Problem: The start menu won't open when I clicked on it. It's completely unresponsive. The other programs located in my task bar were able to be opened, and they were functioning normally.

Only the start menu was not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by restarting Windows Explorer.

I first opened the task manager by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Esc.

Then, I expanded it by clicking on the button in the bottom. (The language of my OS is Finnish. Apologies for that.)

[image: Task manager]

I located Windows Explorer in the "Processes" tab and terminated it by clicking the "end process" button on the lower right.

[image: Task manager, expanded view]

The screen background went black as Explorer was terminated.

Next, I clicked the File menu in the task manager in order to start a new process. I typed in `explorer.exe` in the opening window.

The desktop wallpaper and the task bar were displayed again. And tada, the start menu was working!

Comment: You could also right-click on Explorer and select Restart